# batch file to monitor additions to download folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need a batch file that monitors additions to my Downloads folder, but only new additions. Something like this:

```
:START  

NumOldFiles = GetNumberOfFilesOld  

Delay_30_Seconds  

NumNewFiles = GetNumberOfFilesNew  

if(NumFilesOld < NumFilesNew)  
  run_another_batch_file_I_wrote
  goto START
else
  goto START
```

I do not want to count subfolders, just the folders and files in the directory.
I have been looking at this:
`dir "C:\folder" /b/a |find /v /c "::"`
but I don't know how to store this value and test it as < or >.
Maybe there is a better way to do this, but I can't think of one right now. Maybe maintain a list and if the new list has a new file run the batch script, replace the old list with the new list, I'm not really sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answer 1:

The following snippet should get you going in the right direction. It uses `dir /b` to get a raw list of files and uses `fc` (file compare) to check for differences between each execution of the check.

You could use the Task Scheduler to launch this batch file once every x minutes:

```
@echo off
if not exist c:\OldDir.txt echo. > c:\OldDir.txt
dir /b "d:\My Folder" > c:\NewDir.txt
set equal=no
fc c:\OldDir.txt c:\NewDir.txt | find /i "no differences" > nul && set
equal=yes
copy /y c:\Newdir.txt c:\OldDir.txt > nul
if %equal%==yes goto :eof
rem Your batch file lines go here
```

### Answer 2:

I have always liked a [library of batch functions](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/batchfunctionlibrary/) by Ritchie Lawrence. One of those functions is called [`GetDirStats`](https://github.com/ritchielawrence/batchfunctionlibrary/blob/master/File%20and%20Directory%20Functions/GetDirStats.html).

The `GetDirStats` function returns the number of files, subdirectories and total size of a specified directory. Might be handy for future reference. Although it's only tested on NT4/2000/XP/2003.
Just change `compact/s` to `compact` to not scan subfolders.

Comment: I actually ended up counting the files then comparing them. I gave you the answer cause you were the only one who answered :)

Comment: @Nick Thanks. I updated my answer to include reference to a library function I really like, the library is worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
:START
cls
set /a Old = 0
set /a New = 0
echo Counting files in folder..
for /f "tokens=*" %%P IN ('dir "C:\Users\..." /A /b') do (set /a Old += 1)
set Old
:: delay 60 sec
echo Delaying 60 seconds... (drop new file in)
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 60000>nul
echo Checking for new files..
for /f "tokens=*" %%P IN ('dir "C:\Users\S..." /A /b') do (set /a New += 1)
set New
goto COMPARE

:COMPARE
echo Comparing number of files
if %New% gtr %Old% goto NEWF
goto OLDF

:NEWF
echo New File Detected.
echo.
goto START

:OLDF
echo No New Files.
PAUSE
echo Restarting
echo.
goto START
```

Comment: You could just pass the `dir /b` output through `find /v /c ""` to count; makes it a bit shorter.