# Execute batch file when a new file is added to a folder

Tags: batch-file

I am using the batch file example below that I got from [batch file to monitor additions to download folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230976/batch-file-to-monitor-additions-to-download-folder). I would like to modify this so that it loops through all the subfolders.

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

```
@echo off
if not exist c:\OldDir.txt echo. > c:\OldDir.txt
dir /b "d:\My Folder" > c:\NewDir.txt
set equal=no
fc c:\OldDir.txt c:\NewDir.txt | find /i "no differences" > nul && set equal=yes
copy /y c:\Newdir.txt c:\OldDir.txt > nul
if %equal%==yes goto :eof
rem Your batch file lines go here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please.... make it powershell?

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack  contains the function `Start-FileSystemWatcher`.

Please don't inflict this batch file on any system.

---

[Powershell.com](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/p/5997/9780.aspx) has samples

Here's a sample from [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ITCG/thread/c75c7bbd-4e32-428a-b3dc-815d5c42fd36):

```
$folder = '<full path to the folder to watch>'
$filter = '*.*'                             # <-- set this according to your requirements
$destination = '<full path to the destination folder>'
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
 IncludeSubdirectories = $true              # <-- set this according to your requirements
 NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}
$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
 $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
 $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
 $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
 $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
 Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
 Move-Item $path -Destination $destination -Force -Verbose # Force will overwrite files with same name
}
```

Eventually, unregister the subscription: `Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated`

Comment: do you have any good tutorials you could point me to. The link provided above seems a little more than I need