# Power Shell Script to Monitor Folder for File change and print the information on console

Tags: powershell, file-watcher

Looking for help

I am trying to write a utility that monitors any file change in Folder and print the info on the power shell console

Found lot of help from below question, Thanks to OP and answers in the thread.

[Powershell script to run a .bat file when a file is added to a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405260/powershell-script-to-run-a-bat-file-when-a-file-is-added-to-a-folder/44461673?noredirect=1#comment75919887_44461673)

I have a script something like this now

```
$folder = '\\{Networkname}\Partner1\' # Enter the root path you want to monitor. 
$filter = '*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here. 

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green 
write-host "test"

}
```

When I execute the above script, I am getting below exception

```
Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot subscribe to event. A subscriber with source identifier 'FileCreated' already exists.
At C:\Users\sysadmin\Desktop\FileWatcher.ps1:6 char:21
+ Register-ObjectEvent <<<<  $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.IO.FileSystemWatcher:FileSystemWatcher) [Register-ObjectEvent],
    ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SUBSCRIBER_EXISTS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RegisterObjectEventCommand
```

I just started with Powershell as I need a utility that monitors File change in Folder, please let me know if there is anything that's wrong in the above code, I am just trying to print the changed file information on the console.

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-run the same script, add the following line before the Register-ObjectEvent entry:

```
Unregister-Event FileCreated -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems:

1. You've run the script twice within the same session so an
   event-watcher already exists with the same name.  Use
   `Get-EventSubscriber` to see the registered events within the same
   PowerShell session.
2. You need to move the '`FileCreated`' event in your `Register-ObjectEvent` cmdlet
   to the `-EventName` parameter.

The `-Source-Identifier` parameter is used as a kind of name parameter.

Comment: Yes, `-SourceIdentifier` is a self-chosen name, and the OP chose `FileCreated`. The OP _is_ using the `-EventName` parameter, albeit _positionally_: `Created` is the .NET event name that implicitly binds to `-EventName`