# Batch file to open new file in directory?

Tags: batch-file

I have in `C:\files\` for example the following files:

```
apple.txt
orange.doc
banana.exe
kiwi.avi
```

And I place e.g. `mango.exe` in there.

What script or technique can I use to be notified immediately of the change to this folder and to open the file immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a batch file, this answer may help:

[batch file to monitor additions to download folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230976/batch-file-to-monitor-additions-to-download-folder)

You would need to extend the solution there yourself to launch the detected changes.

In C# this can be done quite easily. This question: [How can I monitor a Windows directory for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760904/how-can-i-monitor-a-windows-directory-for-changes) is similar.

Comment: Thanks man you made my day ;) I got:
@echo off
if not exist c:\OldDir.txt echo. > c:\OldDir.txt
dir /b "d:\My Folder" > c:\NewDir.txt
set equal=no
fc c:\OldDir.txt c:\NewDir.txt | find /i "no differences" > nul && set
equal=yes
copy /y c:\Newdir.txt c:\OldDir.txt > nul
if %equal%==yes goto :eof
rem Your batch file lines go here

Comment: Actually, how do I run it? I still can't see how this script knows that mango.exe is the new one?

Answer (score 0):

```
move \wherever\mango.exe c:\files\mango.exe
start mango.exe
```

Comment: I think they want to watch the directory for changes and as soon as a new file is detected it should be opened.

Comment: @ Joey
Exactly, can you please help me out?